# What's the expression relating conductivity with temperature?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, thermal-conductivity

[image]

In this image, σ is the conductivity, n is the number of electrons per unit volume, λ is the mean free path of the electrons, v (with subscript d) is the drift velocity of electrons, and T is the temperature.

My teacher said that from this expression, we can conclude that conductivity decreases with increase in temperature. But, there's drift velocity in the numerator. Wouldn't that also increase with increase in temperature?

Comment: This derivation conflates the drift velocity of the electrons with their RMS thermal velocity.  In general, they are not the same.

Comment: Looking over my old copy of Ashcroft & Mermin:  the temperature dependence of the conductivity is largely due to a change in the relaxation time $\tau$ due to interactions between electrons and phonons (quantized vibrations of the lattice of nuclei.)  This effect is a quantum mechanical one and can't really be explained via classical models.

Comment: My teacher told me that drift velocity is almost equal to RMS velocity. Is he wrong?

Comment: If I'm remembering things right, the drift velocity is usually much, much smaller than  the thermal velocity.  You can calculate it for typical currents and charge densities in (say) copper and find that it's on the order of cm/sec, while thermal velocities (for an ideal gas at room temperature) are hundreds of meters per second.

Comment: But that said: in the Drude model (which is I think what your teacher is getting at), the average time between collisions time is $\tau = \lambda/v_\text{thermal}$, not $\lambda/v_\text{drift}$.  So the first formula is right if you replaced $v_\text{drift}$ with $v_\text{thermal}$ in the denominator.  This still shows that $\sigma$ should decrease with $T$ (since $v_\text{thermal} \propto \sqrt{T}$), even if the original derivation wasn't quite right.